# Why \%V is not added in visual mode during substitution by default?

Tags: substitute, visual-mode

`\%V` can be used to restrict match within the visual selection. However, I can't think of a situation when one *would not* want to do just that in visual mode.

Comment: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/7915

Answer (score 2):

1. As all Ex-commands `:s` is *linewise*.
2. While executing `:s` you're in Normal mode.
3. If `%\V` is there then the command is restricted to the Visual mode *used last time*.

Comment: When in visual mode, pressing `:` puts `:'<,'>` into the command line, so I don't get point 2. I'm with Tejasvi88: It would be nice if it did `:`<,`>` instead.

Comment: @Quasímodo 1. After pressing enter in cmdline-mode you get into Normal mode, see `:h mode-switching`. 2. It actually honours line range, but it's linewise, see (1).

Answer (score 0):

Probably because it can be achieved easily using a keymap.

```
xnoremap <expr> :s mode()==#'V' ? ':s' : ':s/\%V\%V/<Left><Left><Left><Left>
```