# Configure Vim 8 behavior regarding substitution in visual selection

Tags: substitute, visual-mode

When I select a section of text within a line, then indicate I want to substitute on that line with `:s`, the result is that the entire line is affected.

In order to actually do what I intend, I have to add `\%V` before *and* after the string I want to substitute within the selection, so that no other similar strings are substituted outside of the selection on that line.

Is there a way to configure Vim 8 to behave as I expect it to? That is, if I go to the trouble of selecting text, and I indicate that I want to substitute one thing for another, the substitution takes place within the selection by default.

Comment: There's no such configuration. You can take a look at the answers here for some available approaches (one of which covers the method you mention with \%V): [How to run a substitute command on only a certain part of the line](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/20704). The question there doesn't involve visually selected text but the answers should still have relevance. Likely nothing as convenient as you were hoping for, though.

Comment: Also related: [Vim filter command not using line-wise selection](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/27090/vim-filter-command-not-using-line-wise-selection)

Comment: I *suppose* you could map `:s` in visual-mode, but that could get clunky.

Comment: See also [Why \%V is not added in visual mode during substitution by default?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/29220/why-v-is-not-added-in-visual-mode-during-substitution-by-default)

Comment: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/7915

Answer (score 3):

That is because as all ex commands work linewise.

However you might be able to achieve something desired using an mapping for visual mode. The following maps the `:s` command in visual mode and appends the `\%V` regex atom:

```
 :xnoremap :s :s/\%V
```

(Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to exists an `:xabbrev` command). Note: I don't think it makes sense to add a second `\%V`. Mainly because the regular expression might contain items, that may not need to be included within the last visual selection (think of using e.g. `\ze` or look-around assertions), at least I wouldn't want to have it appended a second time.